# Azure Search within unbounded array of child objects sourced from Cosmos

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

**Requirement**

I have a data model where each "thing" has a number of children and can be represented by JSON like the following.

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "parent_1",
    ... other parent fields ...
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "1_a",
            "name": "child_1_a"
            ... other child fields ...
        },
        {
            "id": "1_b",
            "name": "child_1_b"
            ... other child fields ...
        }
    ]
}
```

The requirement is that we find all the parent things which contain children whose `name` matches a certain pattern.

**Constraints**

We have various constraints:

1. We must store the data in Cosmos with the SQL API.
2. We can only use Azure Search.

**Problem**

Ideally, we would store the each parent "thing" as a whole document in Cosmos with all its children. However, there can be lots of children meaning that the document size sometimes exceeds the 2MB limit for Cosmos documents.

**Things I've tried**

**Attempt 1**

An alternative is to store separate parent and child documents in the same Azure Cosmos collection, distinguish the parents from the children with a `type` field and reference the parent with an `id` field. e.g.

Parent

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "parent_1",
    "type": "parent"
}
```

Child 1

```
{
    "id": "1_a",
    "name": "child_1_a",
    "type": "child",
    "parentId": "1"
}
```

Child 2

```
{
    "id": "1_b",
    "name": "child_1_b",
    "type": "child",
    "parentId": "1"
}
```

However, then searching on the child name can bring back many pages of results for the same parent, so to get only a few parents may require 1000s of pages of matching children to be brought back which is not ideal from a performance point of view.

**Attempt 2**

I thought I could use a JOIN in Cosoms to populate the Azure Search. However, this would need cross document joins which are not supported.

**Other Alternatives**

Other suggestions I've seen are:

- Facet on the id of the parent, but I've read that this would perform badly.
- Batch the children into into batches (e.g. of 500 children) and attach each batch to a parent. If there are multiple batches for a single parent, then denormalise the fields for the parent. This is currently the only option which works for the current data, although it seems to just delay the problem - e.g. at some point it is possible that the number of batches will become large enough to reduce search performance once more.

**Question**

Is it possible to use Cosmos (SQL-API) and Azure Search for this requirement and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you store into Azure Search all the children as individual documents, then just add another property with the parent information you need:

```
{
            "id": "1_a",
            "name": "child_1_a"
            ... other child fields ...,
            "parent": {
                 "parentId":123,
                 "parentName":"x"
                  ... other parent fields ...,
            }    
}
```

your queries should be simplified as well (in my opinion).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried this, but for my data I have the following issue. Say 2 parents have children which match the search. One of the parents has 100000 children which all match the search criteria and the other parent has only 1 matching child. Then to guarantee seeing both parents in the search results, I would have to bring back all 100001 search results leading to poor performance. Is there a way around this which I'm missing here as I'm new to both Cosmos and Azure Search?

Comment: you can try making the parent name as a facetable field.

Comment: Faceting worked well for getting the unique parents - we've gone with this option. Thanks.